# Calling jQuery plugin in AngularDart: no execution, no error, doesn't work at all

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, dart, angular-dart, dart-js-interop

I'm trying to call a `jQuery` plugin from my `Dart` application in `main.dart` with this simple code (which I found on the internet; I'm pretty new to `Dart` and so `angularDart`):

```
import 'dart:js';

void main() {

  bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    // my providers
  ]);

  final options = new JsObject.jsify({
    'menuWidth': 300,      
    'edge': 'left',      
    'closeOnClick': true,      
    'draggable': true
  });
  context.callMethod(r'$', ['.button-collapse'])
         .callMethod('sideNav', [options]);
}
```

But it doesn't do anything at all. It's not working, and also there is not any error! Have you any idea where am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That looks reasonable. Is there also no output on the browser console?

The only thing I can think to check: did you ensure the jQuery plugin is loaded--does it work if you type that js call into the browser console?